# Pandas to_sql sending additional blank rows to db table

Tags: python, sqlite, pandas-to-sql

I am reading a csv file into a dataframe and writing it to a sqlite db table and getting this warning:

```
UserWarning: The spaces in these column names will not be changed. In pandas versions < 0.14, spaces were converted to underscores.
```

dtype=dtype)

The data as 762 rows which I have confirmed at the start of the script and right before the line that writes the file to the db table with:

```
print(dfw.shape)
```

When I look in the database, there are 915 rows and the last 153 rows are all Null.

I am only just learning python and can't think of any reasons for this. A google search on adding additional rows with pandas to_sql has not turned up anything.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Would advise you to check your upload file. If there are rows that had data previously but are not deleted those would be uploaded as blanks. Open your excel and delete the additional rows and then try to upload again.